# An error Url redirected missing port when accessing Admin and removes the port number from the site's URL In Sitefinity CMS V13

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-13

I'm working on a development project with Sitfinity CMS - Version 13.0.

I got an error Url redirected missing port when accessing Admin server by IP/domain:

https://10.x.x.1:803/sitefinity or https://example.com:803/sitefinity.

When we alter any form, however, we receive an error message stating that the form is being diverted to an URL address that does not contain a port and displaying the warning below.

The steps that caused the error:

Step1: Login to admin cms (ex: https://10.x.x.1:803/sitefinity, https://example.com:803/sitefinity)

Step2: Edit content -> Forms - Select edit one form.
Url redirected https://10.x.x.1/sitefinity/... or https://example.com/sitefinity/... missing port 803.

Could you please assist me in determining the cause of the error?
Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this: go to **Administration > Settings > Advanced > System > Site URL Settings** and set the Host and the port there. Check the Enable non-default Stie Url Settings and save.

Restart the site if changes do not apply immediately.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you so much for your feedback.